# Persistent storage of data output in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, persistent-storage

I am developing an app (this is a stripped down version) where the user is able to upload a `.csv` file and perform some automated calculations (in this case just a simple linear model to obtain the `r.squared` value). As there will be a large number of `.csv` spreadsheets to go through (each can all have a unique name), I was wondering whether it would be possible to store all of the `r.squared` values in a single summary table (the second tab), which can then be exported as a single `.csv` file once all the files have been gone through (I am comfortable with the action button to do this last part.

I have two workflow options:

1. Multiple files (or a folder can be loaded at once)
2. Each file is loaded individually

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny) 
ui <- fluidPage(
     navbarPage("Menu",inverse=TRUE,fluid=TRUE,collapsible=TRUE,selected = "Data  input", 
         tabPanel("Data input",
                  sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(
             fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File', 
                       accept=c('text/csv', 
                                'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                '.csv')),
             tags$hr(),
             checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
             radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                          c(Comma=',',
                            Semicolon=';',
                            Tab='\t'),
                          ','),
             radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                          c(None='',
                            'Double Quote'='"',
                            'Single Quote'="'"),
                          '"')
           ),
           mainPanel(
             tableOutput('contents') 
           )
         )),


         tabPanel("Summary",fluidRow(
           column(6,
                  tableOutput("summary")))) 

         ))
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
          mydata<-reactive({
          inFile <- input$file1

          if (is.null(inFile))
          return(NULL)

          data<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
               quote=input$quote)

          data
          })

          output$contents <- renderTable({
          mydata()
          })

          output$summary <- renderTable({

          m<-lm(mydata()[,1]~mydata()[,2])
          summary(m)$r.squared

          })

          }


   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You probably want a global variable http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use `reactiveValues` for this stuff.
It works like a list, but is reactive, so you can change it throughout the session.
Here is an example where I use it to store R squared values which are calculated throughout the session.

It is basically the code you posted above.
In the server, I included a `reactiveValues` object `storage` and a `observeEvent` which just appends `storage$Rsquared` by the R squared whenever `mdata()` is reevaluated.

This is just a basic example.
By adding conditions in the `observeEvent` you can make it more sophisticated.
Or maybe you want to collect more than just a numeric, then you would put another kind of data structure in the `reactiveValue`.

**ui**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Menu",inverse=TRUE,fluid=TRUE,collapsible=TRUE,selected = "Data  input",
    tabPanel("Data input",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File', accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),
          tags$hr(),
          checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
          radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';', Tab='\t'),','),
          radioButtons('quote', 'Quote', c(None='', 'Double Quote'='"', 'Single Quote'="'"),'"')
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents')
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel( "Summary", fluidRow(column(6, tableOutput("summary"))))
))
```

**server**

```
server <- function(input, output)
{
  storage <- reactiveValues(Rsquared = numeric())

  mydata <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if(is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
    data
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    mydata()
  })

  observeEvent(mdata(),{
    m <- lm(mydata()[,1]~mydata()[,2])
    storage$Rsquared <- append(storage$Rsquared, summary(m)$r.squared)
  })

  output$summary <- renderTable(storage$Rsquared)
}
```

Then, you could add a download functionality for the user to save all the R squared values that he created. 
The download function would use `storage$Rsquared` and write it into a .csv for example.